# Xray Cloud test execution status

Tags: cypress, jira, jira-xray, x-ray

Is there a way to obtain the status of every test (passed or failed) of a test execution using API REST in Xray Cloud?

I have a Jira Cloud with Xray where I import a Junit XML and I want to be able to get a file with the status of the test imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you need to use Xray Cloud's [GraphQL API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/GraphQL+API).
Here are some code examples for that:

- in [JavaScript](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/graphql_api_usage/js/test_executions/get_testexecution_testruns.js)
- in [Python](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/graphql_api_usage/python/test_executions/get_testexecution_testruns.py)

You can actually use different GraphQL functions for that but the [getTestExecutions](https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/doc/graphql/gettestexecutions.doc.html) may be the most appropriate one.
You'll need to specify that you want the testRuns object on the results.